# Extend F# Arrays with lookup for bigint

Tags: f#

I would like to extend F# Arrays such that I can use arrays without converting to the finite `int`. Instead I want to work with `bigint` directly.

I was able to add a second length method to the array type as follows:

```
type 'T ``[]`` with

  member this.LengthI: bigint = 
    bigint this.Length

  member this.Item(index: bigint): 'T = 
    this.[int index]
```

However the `Item` method cannot be called with the `.[ ]` syntax.

Any ideas how this could be achieved? I this possible at all?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I don't need it, I just want it ;) The background is that we are using F# for a lecture and because `bigint` (or natural numbers) is easier to reason about than bounded types when trying to prove something about programs, we are planning to use unbounded number types as the default choice. It would have been nice if those number types could just be used with arrays without doing manual conversions every time. We also considered using Scala and Haskell which are a bit more flexible when it comes to working with custom number types, but they just have other drawbacks instead.

Comment: When I asked why you needed it, I meant "why do you need extension methods?". What's wrong with implementing these as functions?

Comment: It's just that `ar.[i]` looks more familiar than `get ar i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect this isn't possible *for native arrays.* You can verify yourself that you can overload indexed access just fine for other collections.

If you compile the following code:

```
let myArray = [| "a" |]
let myList = [ "a" ]

let arrayElement = myArray.[11111]
let listElement = myList.[22222]
```

and inspect the resulting IL, you'll see that while accessing the list element compiles to a regular virtual call, there is a *special CIL instruction* for accessing a native array element, `ldelem`.

```
//000004: let arrayElement = myArray.[11111]
    IL_002c:  call       string[] Fuduoqv1565::get_myArray()
    IL_0031:  ldc.i4     0x2b67
    IL_0036:  ldelem     [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_003b:  stsfld     string '<StartupCode$51dff40d-e00b-40e4-b9cc-15309089d437>'.$Fuduoqv1565::arrayElement@4
    .line 5,5 : 1,33 ''
//000005: let listElement = myList.[22222]
    IL_0040:  call       class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<string> Fuduoqv1565::get_myList()
    IL_0045:  ldc.i4     0x56ce
    IL_004a:  callvirt   instance !0 class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<string>::get_Item(int32)
    IL_004f:  stsfld     string '<StartupCode$51dff40d-e00b-40e4-b9cc-15309089d437>'.$Fuduoqv1565::listElement@5
    IL_0054:  ret
```

I would guess that the same compiler logic that special-case array access to that single instruction also bypass any overload resolution involving extension methods and the like.

One way to circumvent this is to wrap the array in a custom type, where overloaded indexers will work as you expect. Making the wrapper type a struct should reduce the performance loss in most cases:

```
type [<Struct>] BigArray<'T>(array : 'T[]) = 

  member this.LengthI: bigint = 
    bigint array.Length

  member this.Item
      with get(index : int) = array.[index]
      and set (index : int) value = array.[index] <- value

  member this.Item
      with get(index : bigint) = array.[int index]
      and set (index : bigint) value = array.[int index] <- value

let bigArray = BigArray myArray
let bigArrayElement = bigArray.[0]
let bigArrayElement2 = bigArray.[bigint 0]
```

Another one is to upcast the array to the base `System.Array` class, on which you can then define the same overloaded operator. This removes the need to create a wrapper type and duplicate all members of `'T[]`, as you can just upcast/downcast the same array object as necessary. However, since the base class is untyped, you will lose type safety and have to box/unbox the elements when using the indexed access, which is quite ugly:

```
type System.Array with

  member this.Item
      with get (index : int) = (this :?> 'T[]).[index]
      and set  (index : int) (value : 'T) = (this :?> 'T[]).[index] <- value

  member this.Item
      with get(index : bigint) : 'T  = (this :?> 'T[]).[int index]
      and set(index : bigint) (value : 'T) = (this :?> 'T[]).[int index] <- value

let untypedArray = myArray :> System.Array
let untypedArrayElement = box untypedArray.[0] :?> string
let untypedArrayElement2 = box untypedArray.[bigint 0] :?> string
```

Comment: Good answer.  I don't think it's the code that generates the IL that causes this limitation; instead it appears to be the type inference [constraint solver](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/6819e1c769269edefcea2263c98f993e90b623e2/src/fsharp/ConstraintSolver.fs#L1120) which fails to take the possibility of extension properties into account when pretending that string and array types have an indexer.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the case, extensions are silently ignored which is an unfortunate design decision, read this https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3692